# How to switch from many @RequestParam arguments to @ModelAttribute in a Spring Controller method

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller, spring-annotations

I' new to spring and i've managed to collect data from a form in a JSP view and to submit my form to a controller . From the data aquired from the view , i'm instantiating a model object , which also contains other model objects :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEntry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView updateAction(ModelAndView model,
@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "none") String selectedWaveName,
@RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "-1") int id,
@RequestParam(value = "function", defaultValue = "none") String function,
@RequestParam(value = "evidence", defaultValue = "none") String evidence,
@RequestParam(value = "action", defaultValue = "none") String action,
@RequestParam(value = "topicId", defaultValue = "-1") int topicId,
@RequestParam(value = "topic", defaultValue = "none") String topic,
@RequestParam(value = "topicDesc", defaultValue = "none") String topicDesc,
@RequestParam(value = "waveId", defaultValue = "-1") int waveId,
@RequestParam(value = "waveStart", defaultValue = "none") String waveStart,
@RequestParam(value = "waveEnd", defaultValue = "none") String waveEnd)
throws ParseException {

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date dateStart = formatter.parse(waveStart);;
Date dateEnd = formatter.parse(waveEnd);

waveDAO.updateFormResults(new FormResults(id, 
new Topic(topicId, topic, topicDesc), 
new Wave(waveId, selectedWaveName, dateStart, dateEnd), 
evidence, action, function));
return new RedirectView("/hr/?name=" + selectedWaveName);
}
```

How can i replace the whole @RequestParam lines with fewer lines using @ModelAttribute ?
Do i also need to add the @ModelAttribute annotation to the model classes (FormResults , Topic , Wave) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ModelAttribute annotation did work eventually , I found out that when using this annotation , the variables that you're passing from the front end , in my case from the JSP page , should have the exactly same name as the attributes declared in you're model class !

For example if you have a model class like :

```
public class FormResults {

private int id;
private Topic topic;
private Wave wave;
private String evidence;
private String action;
private String manager;
 ... }
```

Also you need getter and setter methods for all the class attributes , and a default constructor !

The variables which you are sending from the JSP page , to the controller method that uses @ModelAttribute annotation ,  would be named like this :

```
<input type="text" name="id"     ...
<input type="text" name="evidence" ...
<input type="text" name="action"   ....
<input type="text" name="manager"  ...
```

And this also works in the case where you have a complex object that has another object as attribute (like in my case : Topic , Wave). 
All you have to do is name those inputs with the prefix of the class name : ex: topic , wave , followed by that classes attributes , ex: topic.id , wave.id ...

And here is my controller method's signature :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEntry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView updateAction(ModelAndView model,
        @ModelAttribute("fr") FormResults fr) throws ParseException {
...}
```

Spring automatically creates a FormResults object . That`s it! :)

Comment: Just a tip for future readers: you can also just create setters with the same name as the parameter (*e.g.* `public void setAction(private String action) {}`), which will be called automatically via Spring. This way you're not constrained to the request param names in your request object (*i.e.* `FormResults`). For example, you could have a `private String lastAction` instead -- just set it appropriately in the setter.

Answer (score 3):

`@ModelAttribute` is not really needed here. What I usually do (but maybe is not good for your case) is an object containing all this data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEntry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView updateAction(ModelAndView model, Options options) throws ParseException {
    ...
}

public static class Options {
    private String selectedWaveName,
    private int id,
    ...
    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: hello , thanks for posting , my question here is : how can i send the object Options options from the jsp page ? because the controller i posted is handling the /updateEntry request from the jsp view , which is processing the data sent from a form , so i don`t know how can this work ?

Comment: @adrianbob: something like `/updateEntry?id=4&selectedWaveName=xxx` would work.